# What are some of the things ROOT can do that could possibly destroy the computer

Tags: debian, gnome, root

I eventually plan on diving into software manipulation, and i want to avoid any and all things that as ROOT could destroy my system. I know tinkering with the file-system are dangerous to mess around in, but is there anything that i should  avoid?

I'm using Debian OS and Gnome workplace interface. Also i haven't started to mess around in the files yet... I just know i can trust the community to help me not mess up the OS.

Comment: Moving or deleting files that keep your computer functional is the first thing that pops in my mind (i.e. files in /bin and/or /usr/bin cannot be added, removed or modified because they are *owned* by root). Files owned by root are like that to prevent you from messing with them (although you have the password). Also, if you are running Linux or have a package manager, you have to be root to install or remove things. I have made Linux crash and burn a couple of times by doing `sudo apt-get autoremove bla` where bla has dependences that are for some reason only tied to bla yet run my computer.

Comment: I think you need to qualify your question somewhat. Are you worried about opening security holes for malicious users of your scripts? Are you worried about the catastrophic repercussions of a simple typo amplified by root powers? Are you looking to avoid mistakes that can "destroy your computer" hardware? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent all users and even root user to login to system if you delete /etc/passwd file.

[Deadly commands that can ruin your system](http://www.howtogeek.com/125157/8-deadly-commands-you-should-never-run-on-linux/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition of what the root user account is, this account can do EVERYTHING & ANYTHING. It can completely destroy the system's filesystem and manipulate anything on the system.

If you're going to do any experimentation such as this, you'll want to do it in a virtual machine, not on your bare metal system. Since this is a learning exercise I would do whatever you want, since you'll only be destroying your virtual machine.

If using something such as Virtualbox, you can create snapshots of your running VM, prior to performing an action within it, to provide you an easier method for recovering from this action more easily.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to his, he is asking possible method or mistakes. Not how u prevent it